# Return last value of array with PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that is used later used by jquery to plot a chart (hence the json_encode).

```
<?php   
    $server = "myserver:1234";
    $user="dbuser";
    $password="userpass";  
    $database = "dbname";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT Y FROM listener_incr";

    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    $i = -60;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($i,$row['Y']);
        $i++;
    }
    $final = json_encode($dataset1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);    
?>
```

The output of $final is `[[-60,5],[-59,3],[-58,6],...[-1,7],[0,8]]`

Aside from the data series being used to plot a chart, I want to echo the last value of my array to a div.

Here is what I have tried...

```
<div id="LastInArray">
  Current count: <?php
   end($dataset1);
   $intOutput = key($dataset1);
   echo $intOutput;
  ?>
</div>
```

But the above outputs `Current count: 59`, which I don't understand. The output I want for the div (in this example) is `Current count: 8`.

Later I want to use AJAX to update this value, which is why it's in a div.

Comment: Well if you are asking for the `key` value, that’s what you are getting … `end` gives you the value of the last array element already as return value, so just use it.

Comment: PHP just does what is told, so your example call to `end()` will output where it is at. A side note to get last element without affecting current array is (it's nasty) `array_shift(array_values($array))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) doesn't traverse your multi-dimensional array iirc. For your value something like `$dataset1[count($dataset1)-1][1]` should be enough.

Comment: @square_eyes fixed. (but should be trivial for anyone ;-) )

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work fine now. I'll go with this solution to avoid using end().

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmp = current($dataset1); // return [-1, 8]
$intOutput = $tmp[1];  // return 8
```

Comment: `$intOutput = current($dataset1)[1];`

Comment: @square_eyes Your dataset1 is an multi dimensional array, $dataset1[], thats the reason you are getting Array as an output for current($dataset1)

Comment: @square_eyes Besides, please avoid `end()` if you can help it. Do a normal loop, especially when you don't look too familiar with PHP. The last thing you want is to dabble with internal pointer when you are not completely in command of the language.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. It's almost working. But displaying the wrong value. I get 5 from the example.

Comment: ...as in I'm having the first value returned. Is this because I have incremented negative numbers in the key?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't working after I took end() out. I put it back and now it works. Should I be using it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_pop` Check the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Comment: Won't this change my array? As I mentioned the array is already used for a chart (which is updated by AJAX too), so I don't want to be messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always count() the number of records in the array and then access its last record with count()-1.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to find out the JSON length first and then using length-1 as key, you can get the value out of key-value pair in JSON.

Comment: Maybe this is safer can you please give me an example?